# Phonegap / Cordova ungzip files on the file system

Tags: cordova, zip, gzip, tar, unzip

Our app is downloading 25MB files from a server and then unzipping them using a cordova plugin.  The problem is unzipping is slow.

Plugin: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.chromium.zip

Has anyone found or created a plugin that can untargz instead of unzip? We have found tar -zx to be about 200% faster than unzip - which would be a huge savings on the phone. For us it would mean a 10-15s savings for the user to decompress these files.

Comment: Did you find a better solution than chromium zip?

Comment: I haven't. But I did find that minimizing the number of files makes it faster. Instead of my 200 separate sound files, I made 1 sound sprite file. Same size, but unzips 280% faster

Comment: Well, I presume my performance issue is due to the number of files - about 50.000 very small JPG (map tiles).

Comment: yep, if you make that a sprite you'd be golden.